# NSIS Installer Creates Random Files

Tags: installation, nsis

When my NSIS installer runs it creates these random files in the same directory that the installer is in.

The files have no extension type(not .txt, etc.) and have a random number as a name like 526310.
[image]

Has anyone else experienced this issue? I have debugged my installer(which is rather complex) and found it occurs when I write to files(not copy/extract files but write). It still could be my installer code doing it but I have debugged for hours and cant find a cause within my own code.

Any ideas what could cause this and how to fix it?

Comment: I have never heard of this before so it is probably your code, look for FileOpen...

Comment: I think it's because of stack. You are probably do something wrong on it.